# android studio view not displayed in designmode

Tags: java, android

I have an androidstudio-project which has not been worked on for some time. When i opened the project, androidstudio did a bunch of updates. Now all the views are not displayed in the design-mode:

[image: Example_Picture]

I have created a new view and i get the same problem. I have tried to clean / rebuild the project. I also tried to invalidate the caches, but the problem is still there. 
I have no error in my project, i can launch the application.

Can someone explain me why this happened and how to fix this?

Comment: try changing Api version from 26 to below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try creating a simple layout? Probably a relative layout with a TextView or so?

Try changing the Api version to a lower one. Check your Manifest for the theme you have set, try changing that also. Also check if your gradle version is the latest and the you are using the latest API version for building your app.

Comment: Changing the "compileSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion" from 24 to 20 and rebuild the project worked. The rebuild failed because of dependencies but after setting them back to 24 and rebuild again, the view is available again. NICE.

Comment: Oh Great...Good job